# PHP return empty value from Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I use the same query to return one integer value between two dates which is a sum of column

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT SUM(TransactionAmount) FROM `sales` WHERE TransactionTime BETWEEN '2020-12-15' AND '2020-12-16'
```

**In this PHP Code:**

```
<?php
require 'config/db.php';

if(isset($_POST["searchinDate-btn"])){
$start_date = $_POST['startdate'];
$end_date = $_POST['enddate'];

$totalRev = "SELECT SUM(TransactionAmount) FROM `sales` WHERE TransactionTime BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'";

$totalRevQ = mysqli_query($conn, $totalRev);

    $rev = mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalRevQ);

      $revenue = $rev[0]; 

 }

?>
```

**(Additional) HTML Code:**

```
<form action="Dashboard.php" method="POST">
      <div class="dateselect"> 
        <label for="start-date">Start Date: </label>
          <input type="date" id="start-date" name="startdate" value="">
        <label for="start-date"> - - End Date: </label>
          <input type="date" id="end-date" name="enddate" value="">
          <button  style="margin-bottom: 3px;" type="submit" name="searchinDate-btn" class="mbtn btn btn-primary">Show</button>  
      </div>
</form>
<p> <?php echo $revenue; ?> </p>
```

The Variable revenue return nothing for some reason!
Note: Both start date and end date and the query result actually return results but I think there is a problem with showing the result of the query which will be one integer value like 562 or something else! ( I need the value of the row number 0 not the count of the rows)

**UPDATE**: The wrong was in passing date type from PHP to compare it with timestamp field type at the database.

to convert date to time stamp I use this PHP Code:

```
<?php
    require 'config/db.php';
    
    if(isset($_POST["searchinDate-btn"])){
    $start_date = $_POST['startdate'];
    $StartDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($start_date));
    $end_date = $_POST['enddate'];
    $EndDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($end_date + '24 hours'));
    
    $totalRev = "SELECT SUM(TransactionAmount) AS Revenue FROM `sales` WHERE TransactionTime BETWEEN '$StartDate' AND '$EndDate'";
    
    $totalRevQ = mysqli_query($conn, $totalRev);
    
    $rev = mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalRevQ);
    
    $revenue = $rev['Revenue'];
    
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: As an aside, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: I use such type of security in authuncation controller, if there is no established session by login or registration it will refuse to authuncate also I use bind_param for both login and registration form is that enhough ?

Comment: No. Never use string concatenation.

Comment: I use this:

 if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
  header('location: Login.php');
  exit();
}

Comment: @Dharman no this return a count of rows number, I need the value of the row number 0.

Comment: It's the same principle. You need to use the correct function or use an SQL alias. Please read my answer carefully

Comment: The wrong was in passing date type from PHP to compare it with timestamp field type at the database, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you used `mysqli_fetch_assoc` function you need to set a name for the result (I this name to "AmountSum" in my example):

```
<?php
require 'config/db.php';

if(isset($_POST["searchinDate-btn"])){
$start_date = $_POST['startdate'];
$end_date = $_POST['enddate'];

$totalRev = "SELECT SUM(TransactionAmount) AS AmountSum FROM `sales` WHERE TransactionTime BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'";

$totalRevQ = mysqli_query($conn, $totalRev);

$rev = mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalRevQ);

$revenue = $rev['AmountSum'];

}
?>
```

Comment: The wrong was in passing date type from PHP to compare it with timestamp field type at the database, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding an alias to the sum in the query:

```
$totalRev = "SELECT SUM(TransactionAmount) AS totalAmount FROM `sales` WHERE TransactionTime BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'";
```

Then changing `$rev = mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalRevQ)` to `$rev = mysqli_fetch_array($totalRevQ)`, in order to get the value with `$revenue = $rev["totalAmount"]` :D

Also, as Strawberry said, don't forget to protect that query from SQL injection, it's never good to trust user input!

Comment: Unfortunately this not fix my problem I use your solution before you answer but it does not works, it is kind of weird problem !

Comment: @Hussein Run the SQL in the console or something like phpmyadmin and see the output.

Comment: The wrong was in passing date type from PHP to compare it with timestamp field type at the database, thank you.